# How can I embed a .m3u music stream in a website and display song name

Tags: html, web, stream, audio-player, m3u

I thought my question could easily be solved with a bit of googling, but no, I have not found any clue on how to embed a `.m3u` music stream into a website AND display the name of the current song...

Embedding the stream was really easy:

```
<audio ref="audio" countrols="controls">
   <source src="http://DOMAINTOSTREEM/streamname?type=.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">      
</audio>
```

But I have no clue how to retrieve the streaming information from it.
It plays the music but that's it.

If I download the .m3u file and open it in VLC Player it does display the song's name! So the information must be somewhere...

Using the network tool was not successful at all and I have no idea where to further look.
So any hint on that would be super helpful.

Cheers